# Как записать несколько рандомных чисел в массив

Tags: javascript

```js
//Функция высчитывающая рандомное число 
function randomNumber(arg) {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * arg);
    return randNum;
}
 
 var summ =  randomNumber(100); // передача аргумента  функции , присвоение результата в переменную

document.write("Рандомное число : " + summ + "</br>");

var arrRandNumber = new Array(100); // создание массива с  обьявленной длинной

arrRandNumber.unshift(summ);  // добавление в массив рандомного числа 

document.write("Рандомное число  записанное в массив, первый элемент : " + arrRandNumber[0] + "</br>");

document.write("Рандомное число  записанное в массив[0],  и  99 undefined : " + arrRandNumber);
```

не понимаю как  написать код , который  будет  записывать в массив рандомное число в каждый новый индекс(0,1,2,3,,,,,99) с каждой новой итерацией. Длинна массива 100 т.е ( 0 - 99).

Comment: Рандомное число записывается в массив точно так же как обычное. Я думаю, вы значительно быстрее найдете ответ на свой вопрос если перестанете искать специфичные для рандомных чисел способы.

Comment: И что же именно вы не можете написать? Создание массива? Добавление в него элементов? Вывод получившегося массива?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то подобное должно получиться:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    arr.unshift(randomNumber(100));
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: посмотри еще раз)